# C# outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

I am getting the error " Index was outside the bounds of the array". This code that I typed from my text book. Cant seem to find anything wrong with it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] scores = new int[8];
        int x;
        string inputString;

        for (x = 0; x < scores.Length; ++x)
        {
            Write("Enter your score on test {0} ", x + 1);
            inputString = ReadLine();
            scores[x] = Convert.ToInt32(inputString);
        }

        WriteLine("\n----------------------------");
        WriteLine("Scores in original order: ");
        for(x = 0; x < scores.Length; ++x)
            Write("{0, 6}", scores[x]);

        WriteLine("\n----------------------------");
        Array.Sort(scores);
        WriteLine("Scores in sorted order: ");
        for(x = 0; x < scores.Length; ++x)
            Write("{0, 6}", scores[x]);

        WriteLine("\n----------------------------");
        Array.Reverse(scores);
        WriteLine("Scores in reverse order: ");
        for(x = 0; x < scores.Length; ++x) ;
            Write("{0, 6}", scores[x]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Step through line by line in a debugger. If you don't know how to use a debugger yet, read up on it. That one tool will save you countless hours of wasted time, and help you better understand program flow.

Comment: try `x++` instead of `++x`

Comment: @Phaeze how would that even matter? For an expression that is only a single variable, prefix vs postfix does not matter.

Comment: @Phaeze in this case this nothing change.

Comment: @Phaeze: Doesn't matter.

Comment: Wasn't sure that why I commented it. post fix is generally the standard, can't actually remember the last time I had to prefix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra semicolon

```
for (x = 0; x < scores.Length; ++x) ;
Console.Write("{0, 6}", scores[x]);
```

The `for` loop runs, doing nothing except increment `x` to the final value of 8. Then the next line runs with `x` still having the value from before, which happens to be 8.

To fix it, remove the extra `;`.

Comment: Good eyes ;-) or fast compiling :D

Comment: As a matter of personal style, I generally use { } even for 1-line loop bodies. My eye was drawn to that line as a result.

Comment: Or just format your code. Voilà - look what has no indent